# Create a service to initialize my application with Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to create a service to initialize my whole application. It should for example calls for the first time my function "refreshDatas" which will try to refresh datas every 7seconds :

```
    app.service('dataRefreshServices', function($http, userService, serverConfigService) {
$this = this;       
var listDatas = [];
        var listMessages = [];

        // Communication with the server
        $this.getServerUri = function()
        {
            return serverConfigService.getServerUri()+"majsvc/";
        };




        // Fonctions de rafraichissement
        $this.GetDataFromServer = function()
        {
            alert('Im here');
            var uri = this.getServerUri();



var promises = {};
                /* Commenting this part the time the function calling isn't working if(userService.user().isLogged())
                {
                    promises = $http.get(uri)
                    .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                        // this callback will be called asynchronously
                        // when the response is available
                        return data;
                    }).
                    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                        // called asynchronously if an error occurs
                        // or server returns response with an error status.
                        return "";
                    });
                }*/
            return promises;    
        };

        $this.RefreshDatas = function () {
                alert('im here 1');
                $this.listDatas = $this.GetDataFromServer().then(function(promise){
                alert('refreshing the list');
                $timeout(this.RefreshDatas , 7000);
                });
            }();

    });
```

My application controller :

```
app.controller('ApplicationController', function($scope, $rootScope, $location, userService, serverConfigService, serverConnexionServices, dataRefreshServices, InitializationServices){

        $scope.message = 'Everyone come and see how good I look! Logged :'+ userService.user().isLogged;
        this.IsUserLogged = function()
        {
            return userService.user().isLogged;
        };

        this.InitializeApplicationConfiguration = function()
        { // Start the initialization of the server's configuration
            dataRefreshServices.RefreshDatas();
        };


        this.LogOut = function()
        {
            serverConnexionServices.LogOut();
        };
        });
```

The initialize function is called in the body of my index.html :

```
<body  data-ng-controller="ApplicationController as controller" ng-init="controller.InitializeApplicationConfiguration()">
```

When I launch my application I get a "undefined is not a function" on the line "this.listDatas = this.GetDataFromServer().then(function(promise){"

I understand the function refresh is called before my "GetDataFromServer" function is initialized but how can I manage to make this work ? maybe initialize my application on the ng-init is not the best way ?

Thank you

**EDIT** Code updated after answer hints

Answer (score 0):

'this' is dependent on the execution context and may be re-defined in your callbacks. You should save 'this' in a temp variable, and then reference it.

```
 var $this = this;
 $this.refreshData = function(...)
```

Also, ng-init is not the right place to call an initialization function.  Execute initialization code inside your controller.

```
app.controller('ApplicationController', function($scope, $rootScope, $location, userService, serverConfigService, serverConnexionServices, dataRefreshServices, InitializationServices){

        ...
         this.InitializeApplicationConfiguration();
   });
```

Comment: I tried to put "$this" instead of "this" and put my initialization inside my controller.
It goes in the GetDataFromServer function (I can see the alert box "Im here") but I have the same error after (undefined is not a function). Something I missed ?

Comment: I managed to make it work doing your solution but my initialization function is called twice, why ?